# Training Keras Model : Graph Execution Error (callbacks = callbacks)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, voice-recognition

Following the Deep Learning Cookbook, for voice recognition. On the last step, when the epochs start, the following code is breaking at callbacks = callbacks:

```
history = model.fit_generator(
 generator=batch_generator(X_train, batch_size),
 steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
 epochs=n_epochs,
 verbose=1,
 validation_data=batch_generator(X_val, 32),
 validation_steps=5,
 callbacks=callbacks
 )
```

[image]

Comment: Please read the error, it says your data has negative values where these are not expected, from there you should check your data and see if this is true or not.

Comment: also looks like the stack trace is collapsed, so the actual place you care about the error likely is hidden in your screenshot